# WCF REST JSON Service returns error 404 / Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I followed this example to make my first WCF service: [WCF REST Service JSON](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON), then edited it to create my own. I was able to get my service to run fine in debugging using ASP.NET Developer Server. I opened port 8081(on the Server, Firewall and Router) and then assigned it to the "Registration" folder in IIS. I then published the service to a Windows Server 2003 running IIS 6 after spending a day figuring out I had to use MsDeployAgentService. I then set the ASP.NET version to 4.0.3019 using the IIS.  The Registration folder contains Service1.svc, Web.config, and the bin folder.

This is my web config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ServiceApp.Properties.Settings.RegistrationConnection"
      connectionString="Data Source=EDITED;Initial Catalog=Registration;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=EDITED;Password=EDITED;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="524288" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamedRequestWebBinding"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard"
                 sendTimeout="10:15:00"
                 openTimeout="10:15:00"
                 receiveTimeout="10:15:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="StreamedRequest">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceApp.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address=""  binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" contract="ServiceApp.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
          </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I try to consume the service with a test client I get Error 404 with the following statement

```
byte[] data = client.DownloadData("http://ServerIP:8081/Registration/Service1.svc/CheckSoftware/1/Customer1/1_0/abc123/1/1");
```

When I remove the port I get an Error 401 "Not Authorized"

```
byte[] data = client.DownloadData("http://ServerIP/Registration/Service1.svc/CheckSoftware/1/Customer1/1_0/abc123/1/1");
```

I have tried using the LAN IP aswell as the WAN IP address.

Followed [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1807824.aspx/1) because it looks liked the OP followed the same example and had simalar problems but It didn't help.

I then looked in the Event Viewer on the server and found this when I included in the port number:

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/23878916
 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The service '/Registration/Service1.svc' does not exist. ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: The service '/Registration/Service1.svc' does not exist.
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: w3wp


 Process ID: 3460
```

I can clearly see the Service1.svc file exist in the folder. I am pretty lost at this point and would appreciate any help.

**EDITED TO INCLUDE MORE CODE:**

```
    namespace ServiceApp
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
          UriTemplate = "/CheckSoftware/{SoftwareId}/{CustomerId}/{Version}/{Key}/{MoboID}/{ProcessorID}",
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        SoftwareStatus CheckSoftware(string SoftwareID, string Version, string CustomerID, string Key, string moboID, string processorID);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
          Method = "GET", 
          UriTemplate = "/SaveKey/{SoftwareId}/{CustomerId}/{Key}/{MoboID}/{ProcessorID}",
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string SaveKey(string SoftwareID, string CustomerID, string Key, string moboID, string processorID);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class FileInformation
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public byte[] Content
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class SoftwareKey
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string SoftwareId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string CustomerId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Version
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Key
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SoftwareStatus
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Boolean SoftwareId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public Boolean CustomerId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public Boolean Version
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public Boolean Key
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public Boolean HardwareID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Check your file structure, do you have a folder and a file in it '/Registration/Service1.svc'

Comment: I have a folder called Registration with the Service1.svc file in it on the servers C drive

Comment: can you show us the UriTemplate from the interface? Actually show us the the whole interface declaration with decorations.

Comment: Also, if it's a RESTful WCF service, the use of the client makes me kinda O_o

Comment: Have you tried simply browsing to http://ServerIP:8081/Registration/Service1.svc/CheckSoftware/1/Customer1/1_0/abc123/1/1 ??

Comment: Browsing gets me the same error 404.

Comment: Yeah, something is wrong with the url. Make sure that your service is running properly in the background before trying this. As in run the project, then check the service host to make sure it's running, not 'ERROR'. Then try removing the svc file extension so that it is http://ServerIP:8081/Service1/CheckSoftware/1/Customer1/1_0/abc123/1/1, try browsing to it. Actually, when you run it locally like this, the virtual host will give you the address where it is accessible. Try that. Anything other than 404 will be a success at this stage

Comment: oh and remove the first / in the UriTemplate

Comment: First I removed the beginning "/" from the UriTemplate. Then I removed the .svc from the address, but I still got a error 404 on the server. Then I tried running it on my local machine with the ASP.NET Developement Server and still got error 404.

Comment: I reverted my changes back to the code in the OP that works on the  ASP.NET Developement Server and IIS Express in debugging. I then removed "/Registration" from the URL and everything worked. So I guess I don't need the folder name when accessing a service.

Comment: Nope. Just remember that you're not pointing to a application running on a port, not a virtual directory :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using IIS 6.0 for a Service I didn't need to include the folder name in the URL. So simply changing one line of code solved my problems.

```
byte[] data = client.DownloadData("http://ServerIP:8081/Service1.svc/CheckSoftware/1/Customer1/1_0/abc123/1/1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your UriTemplate set up correctly? The 404 error suggests that it isn't making contact with the service/method at all.

REST services are simple web apis, instead of trying to import the service like you would a normal WCF service, try a normal http request (just a bare example, not a solution):

```
    //declare the request (not sure of your uri, so i guessed)
    var queryString = string.Format("1/{0}/1_0/{1}/1/1", Param1, Param2);
    var req = 
        HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ServerIP:8081/Registration/Service1.svc/CheckSoftware/"); //base address of service
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    //build the fields stream
    var fields = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(queryString);
    req.ContentLength = fields.Length;

    //put the request info into the stream
    var requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fields, 0, fields.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    //execute the request
    var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    //pull your infos
    var statusCode = (int)resp.StatusCode;
    var body = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```